# Determine the asymptotic distribution of $\bar X_n$, properly centered and $\sqrt n$ scaled

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1, X_2,...X_n$ be i.i.d. with $P(X_i =1)=1-P(X_i =0)=p,p \in (0,1)$.
(a) Show that $\bar X_n$ is the MLE of p.
(b) Find the mean $\mu_n$ and variance $\sigma^{2}_n$ of $\bar X_n$ and invoke the CLT to determine the asymptotic distribution of $\bar X_n$, properly centered and $\sqrt n$ scaled.

**Thoughts:** I know how to solve part (a) and also know the mean and variance of part (b). The question that bothers me is the second part of part (b). I don't know to apply CLT here with $\sqrt n$ scaled. Any explicit explanation of this part would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a review of some facts I suppose you already know.

$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim Binom(n, p).$ Also, $E(X_i) = p\;$
and $V(X_i) = p(1-p).$
Thus, $E(S_n) = np\;$ and $SD(S_n) = \sqrt{np(1-p)}.$

If we define $Z_n = \frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}},$ then
$Z_n$ is approximately standard normal. According the the CLT
its distribution gets closer to standard normal as $n$ increases.
I assume this is what is meant by 'centered and $\sqrt{n}$-scaled'.

Given that $\bar X = S_n/n,$ you ought to be able to
re-express the fraction for $Z_n$ in the required format.

Comment: thanks!!! BTW, what is V? Is that the variance? If so, I think it should be $p(1-p)$. What does SD mean here?

Comment: Right. My mistake. Fixing it. Thanks. SD=standard deviation.